# how to init arguments in User class

Tags: locust

I create a User class with some init arguments, but got TypeError as below when executed :"locust -f stress.py --headless -u 100 -r 100 -t 1m"

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 906, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/runners.py", line 406, in 
> lambda: super(LocalRunner, self).start(user_count, spawn_rate, wait=wait)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/runners.py", line 314, in start
> self.spawn_users(user_count, spawn_rate=spawn_rate, wait=wait)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/runners.py", line 206, in spawn_users
> spawn()
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/runners.py", line 199, in spawn
> new_user = user_class(self.environment)
> TypeError: **init**() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'uid', 'room_id', 'action_uid', and 'appkey'

```
class JoinRoomUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 2.5)
    host = ''

    def __init__(self, env, uid, room_id, action_uid, appkey):
        self.env = env
        self.uid = uid
        self.room_id =room_id
        self.action_id = action_uid
        self.appkey = appkey
```

how to init these arguments?

the task in locust script as below.

```
@task
def join_room(self):
host = 'xxxxxxx'
body = {
    "room_id": self.room_id,
    "userid": self.action_uid,
    "uid": self.action_uid
}
rsp = self.client.post(url, json=body, headers=get_header(self.appkey))
```

if I exectue "locust -f StressTest/stress.py 'Qa' 123456 '101013' 686868 'eos'  --headless -u 100 -r 100 --run-time 1m" , then throw " bogon/ERROR/locust.main: Unknown User(s): Qa, 686868, 123456, 101013, eos" error.

Answer (score 2):

Try use *args, **kwargs and super() when inherit from Parent class. For that particular case, you don't provide uid, room_id, action_uid, appkey variables on the step of initialization, because HttpUser inherited from User, which has only one 1 argument - environment

```
class SimpleSendRequest(User):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

for User class is more suggested to inherit from User class [doc](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#httpuser-class)

if you really required to set variables to daughter object, you can set it on the step of initialization, just like that:

```
def __init__(self, env, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(env, *args, **kwargs)
    self.uid = your_map['uid']
    self.room_id = your_map['room_id']
    self.action_id = your_map['action_uid']
    self.appkey = your_map['appkey']
```

the only question, how are you going to use them

to add custom arguments, via CLI check [github](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/add_command_line_argument.py):

```
    @events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
def init_parser(parser):
    parser.add_argument("--customarg", type=str, env_var="LOCUST_MY_ARGUMENT", default="1234", help="It's working")

@events.init.add_listener
def _(environment, **kw):
    print("Custom argument supplied: %s" % environment.parsed_options.customarg)
```

to get it inside your class JoinRoomUser **init**, use:

```
print(self.environment.parsed_options.customarg)
```

and run like:

```
locust -f locustfile.py --customarg CUSTOM_VALUE --headless -u 10 -r 10 --run-time 5s
```

Comment: I want to put the locust script into my Django project. other .py script will call the locust script by command. so I set some init param in the locust script.

Comment: @Peter you can create custom ClientClass and override send method there. Pass all of your variables to that client and set that client to user self.client variable. Works for me well.

Comment: thanks for your advices, I put these variables into a json files, and get these in init method

def get_param():
    f = open("param.json", "r")
    data = json.load(f)
    return data

class JoinRoomUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 2.5)
    host = ''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        data = get_param()
        self.uid = data["uid"]
        self.room_id = data["room_id"]
        self.action_uid = data["uid"]
        self.appkey = data["appkey"]

Comment: @Peter did it help?

Comment: the method get variables from json file is work for me, I don't know how to write code from your advices. <_>

Comment: @Peter import map to .py file where you are going to use it. file or imported map all the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229762/discussion-between-vova-and-peter).